# Select all values from a column til last value

Tags: excel, vba

In column A I have several values. As values ​​are added or removed, in excel vba I want to extract all values ​​from column A down to the last value

How can i create this?

```
Werte = Sheets("Messauswertung").Range("A1:A100").Value
```

This is not a the optimal way

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Answer (score 1):

On way is

```
dim lastRow as Long
With Sheets("Messauswertung")
   lastRow = .Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row
   Werte = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
End With
```

By the way, each sheet has a .Name but also a .CodeName (Sheet1).
I find it much better to (eventually change the CodeName and) use that one.
Easier to read, to write, and protected from name changes by users.